# how to use left join in linq

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to write left join by using linq but it gives an error. This is sql code:

```
        Select  
          Case s.StudentID
          When 1000 Then s.Amount
          End As Amount
        From    Student s
        Left Join Course cOn c.Time = s.ForDate And c.StudentID= s.ID And s.Amount= 1000
```

This one is I tried code but it gives an error for left join:

```
       from s in Student
         join c in Course
                                          on new {s.ForDate , s.ID}
                                          equals new { c.Time, c.StudentID}                                     
                                          into inj

                                            from i in inj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                            where s.Amount= 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from s in Student
         join c in Course  on new {A=s.ForDate ,B= s.ID}
                           equals new {A= c.Time,B= c.StudentID}                                     
                           into inj
                           from i in inj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where s.Amount == 1000
                           select new{
                           ///
                           }
```

Comment: make sure s.ForDate and c.Time are the same type or you need to use a cast

Comment: It gives  error where s.Amount= 1000. I tried also inj.Amount but still gives an error

Comment: i missed an = operator in where clause.check it again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from s in Student.Where(p=>p.Amount == 1000)
join c in Course on new {s.ForDate , s.ID} equals new { c.Time, c.StudentID} into inj from i in inj.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is very peculiar and doesn't seem to do much that is useful, but the translation is:

```
from s in Student
where s.Amount == 1000
select (s.StudentID == 1000 ? s.Amount : null)
```